# React - setInterval inside an onChange event

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to set setInterval inside an onChange event, like mostly it is done on componentDidMount.

I have 2 dropdowns that filter data and then render a table, the dropdowns are controlled by onChange methods. The last on change method has a request that needs to be re-polled every X # seconds to get updated information from the server. However, these methods are outside of cDM so I'm not sure how to handle the `setInterval` like I previously have.

```
cDM() {
    //axios call, update state with fetched data
}

onChange1 () {
    // uses data from cDM to render the options in a dropdown.
    // another axios call based on the selection, fetches data to render more options in subsequent dropdown
}

onChange2 () {
    //dropdown 2 use data from onChange1 axios call. After the selection from the dropdown is made, it makes an api call that then renders data to a table. 
    //Some of this data updates every 5 seconds, so I need to re-poll this service to get updated information from the server.
}
```

if all the data was in `cDM` I'd normally change the data requests in `cDM` to an arrow function to avoid `setState` issues, call the function inside/outside of the `setInterval` callback with the following:

```
componentDidMount() {
this.interval = setInterval(() => this.getData(), 10000);
this.getData();
}

componentWillUnMount() {
clearInterval(this.interval);
}

getData = () => {
//data requests
}
```

Comment: Just a note: `this` poiner in `setInterval` doesn't point to the component's `this`. the first line should be like this:
`var that=this; this.interval = setInterval(() => that.getData(), 10000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SetInterval does not wait for the AJAX response before polling starts over again.  This can become extremely buggy/memory intensive in the event of network problems.

I would suggest you use a setTimeOut and every update I would put a piece of response data in state and start the timer upon state changes inside your render function.   That way you always ensure you get your result back before pounding the server again and bogging down your client's UI.

Comment: Yes, with the data not all being fetched at once inside `cDM` it becomes tricky waiting for the response before re-polling the service. Do you have an example of using `setTimeout` waiting for results before hitting the server again?

Comment: I can try to provide one soon, but I would say, in your success or error callback on the ajax call, that is where you want to make your subsequent ajax calls and when your finished making them, I would then in that final success callback, fire off my custom component method to update the state.

Comment: At the same time, while updating the state, I would reset the timer.   SetTimeout just takes in a function that will be executed, and the second argument is the amount of time to wait before that function is executed.

Comment: Here's a codesandbox I made up to elaborate on my issue with a little more detail. https://codesandbox.io/s/qq0k5wmwj6

Answer (score 0):

- Place the code of componentDidMount body into both onChange events.
- Set Interval equal to some state variable, so on componentWillUnmount you can access that interval and remove it.

  ```
  onChange () {    
      // Change Logic
      ....

      // Interval logic
      clearInterval(this.state.interval); //Clear interval everytime.

      this.state.interval = setInterval(() => this.getData(), 10000);
      this.getData();
  }

  componentWillUnMount() {
      clearInterval(this.state.interval);
  }
  ```

Comment: I'm not sure placing the initial call in `cDM` in both `onChange` methods will work as expected. Each onChange is dependent on the previous onChange. `cDM` gets an initial list of data, select an option which is controlled by `onChange1` then that filters more data for the second dropdown. Upon selecting an option from the second drop down, controlled by `onChange2`, it renders the corresponding data to a table

Comment: Actually it should work like this:
getData() should get values of both dropdowns stored in 2 state variables, and get Data from api on the basis of them.
So when you call getDate() on onChange, getData will read values of both dropDowns updated in state Variable and and get data on basis of those 2 values irrespective of which onChange it is called on.

Comment: Only when the data is rendered to the table do I need to re-poll the service I'm requesting in the second `onChange`

Comment: Also the data request are made inside the `onChange` methods so I'm not sure what `this.getData()` inside `onChange` in your example is referring to

Answer (score 0):

You can indeed place this in your update event handler - event handlers do not have to be pure. There is the minor issue that doing this means that your view is no longer a function of state + props, but in reality that's not usually a problem.

It seems your *main* concern is how you model this data.

One way to do this might be to use a higher order component or some kind of composition, splitting the display of your component from the implementation of the business logic.

```
interface Props<T> {
  intervalMilliseconds: number
  render: React.ComponentType<ChildProps<T>>
}

interface State<T> {
  // In this example I assume your select option will be some kind of string id, but you may wish to change this.
  option: string | undefined
  isFetching: boolean
  data: T
}

interface ChildProps<T> extends State<T> {
  setOption(option: string | undefined): void
}

class WithPolledData<T> extends React.Component<Props<T>, State<T>> {
  interval: number

  componentDidMount() {
    this.setupSubscription()
  }

  componentDidUnmount() {
    this.teardownSubscription()
  }

  setupSubscription() {
    this.interval = setInterval(() => this.fetch(), this.props.intervalMilliseconds)
  }

  teardownSubscription() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }

  componentDidUpdate(previousProps: Props, previousState: State) {
    if (previousProps.intervalMilliseconds !== this.props.intervalMilliseconds) {
      this.teardownSubscription()      
    }
    if (previousState.option !== this.state.option && this.state.option !== undefined) {
      this.fetch()
    }
  }

  fetch() {
    if (this.props.option === undefined) {
      // There is nothing to fetch
      return
    }

    // TODO: Fetch the data from the server here with this.props.option as the id
  }

  setOption = (option: string | undefined) => {
    this.setState({ option })
  }

  render() {
    return React.createElement(
      this.props.render,
      {
        ...this.state,
        setOption: this.setOption
      }
    )
  }
}
```

You could use this component like so:

```
<WithPolledData intervalMilliseconds={5000} render={YourComponent} />
```

`YourComponent` would call `setOption()` whenever a drop down option was selected and the fetching would happen in the background.

This is how you would *technically* do this. I agree with @ChrisHawkes that using setInterval like this is likely a mistake - You would at the very least need to cancel in-flight HTTP requests and you run the risk of causing issues on devices with poor network performance.

Alternatively, a *push* rather than a *pull* model may be better here - This scenario is exactly what WebSockets are designed for and it wouldn't require too much modification to your code.

Comment: I'm looking into `websockets`, not entirely sure where to start with the modification.